# Aborting a long-running CGI script written in C++ from client with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, c++, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cgi

I have a CGI script written in C++ which performs a relatively simple loop in a brute force evaluation of a scheduling-type problem. Parameters are collected from a database, and the CGI script is called from the web browser in JavaScript using an XMLHttpRequest passing the parameters in a POST request. This works fine. But sometimes it takes too long, and I would like to have the user be able to abort the script by clicking on a button in the browser while the script is running.

I have resorted to polling a little file from inside the CGI script. The file can contain either '0' or '1', indicating that the script should abort. This works, too. However, the file I/O itself takes a lot of time relatively speaking, and I was wondering if there is more elegant way of doing this? I can only check it every 4 or 5 million iterations, otherwise I run into problems. I can live with that, but I am wondering if I could do it with an environment variable, for example?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: If you have an api to start the process, why not simply write one more to stop the process? I'm assuming of course that you have access to the server handling the start request

Comment: @JibiAbraham [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) - already written and standardize, gets its input using env-vars at start time. Do you suggest to write a new CGI standard?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Though I do not appreciate the tone; there is something on the backend capable of handling http requests. I meant for the OP to add support for one more request to that knows how to handle stopping the script

Comment: @JibiAbraham Apologies... but there was no tone. I just raised a question. "I meant for the OP to add support for one more request to that knows how to handle stopping the script " If relying purely on CGI (this is what your "an api to start the process" means), since the executor script gets its input *exclusively* from env-vars, any other script attempting to stop will need to rely on "process killing" - letting DB connection hanging until timeout, temp files and whatnot. Not very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some preliminary tests, it seems that the shared memory facilities offered by PHP `shmop` will be the easiest and safest to use in the current server environment available to me. Many thanks to Adrian Colomitchi who pointed me in the right direction (RAM disk == shared memory)!

Answer (score 0):

CGI is inflexible, so any solution should rely on other means.

Copying strategies:

1. put that file on a RAM-disk - the file IO should go down
2. replacing FS signaling with TCP ones. Make the executor script open a socket to an "abort daemon" listening to a dedicated port. If the executor script "socket peeks" if even one byte available from the "abort daemon", it aborts.  Once started, the executor script will need to just communicate the opened port to the "aborting page". Another script, which is URL-pointed by the "Abort" button will need to communicate the "abort daemon" which port to send "a killer byte".

---

With the extra info about the server running PHP, you may try a PHP cache as a mechanism for messaging - see [APC store](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) and related.

Other caches seems to exist - a [list of others](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/PHP_Caching_solutions_and_performance) here.

---

Perhaps an overkill - [redis](http://redis.io/) - they say

> Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as database, cache and message broker.

Has, among a huge list of [supported languages](http://redis.io/clients), C and PHP. Seems notable enough to have a [wikipedia](http://redis.io/community) entry.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Adrian ... I like the idea of using TCP, but I'm not sure whether our IT admin will agree to open up a port for this due to security considerations. I was thinking more along the lines of setting an environment variable from PHP which could be done with another Ajax request, but haven't done much with setting environment variables from PHP yet.  Would the script see any changed variables after it was started, or are they fixed at startup?

Comment: Server in question is Apache 2 running on Linux Debian, BTW.

Comment: @RobertHairgrove - try a RAM-disk first - might be just enough. In re TCP, the client will never make a direct connection to the server (other than http interaction), I think you sysadm might be more pliable if that port will be opened only by localhost.

Comment: @RobertHairgrove now that you told me about PHP, see my extra suggestions of using PHP caches

Comment: PHP caching looks interesting, and I appreciate the links because this is new information for me. But the CGI script we are talking about is written in C++ and I don't know how it would be able to access anything in PHP land once it has started?

Comment: @RobertHairgrove Some of the *might* have an API that you can link your program against.

Comment: Our Apache server seems to have `shmop` support enabled, which -- as far as I can tell -- means that I should be able to use the System V IPC functions `ftok()` & Co. to generate a key which I can share with the CGI script by passing the key in a POST variable. Since I've never done this before, can anyone point me to some FAQs or common gotchas doing it this way? Or will it even work?